# Angular populating table with object data that has missing fields

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i'm currently working on displaying large amounts of data in tables for a scientific project. i have timeStamps of experiments, which look like this:

```
interface TimeData {
   time: string;
   data: {SD: string, SEM: string, N: string, MEAN: string};
}
```

i have a total of 11 timeStamps in the table, all described by their 'time', e.g. 15, 30, 60, 90...

if an experiment is missing a timestamp completely or has no data for the timestamp 30 at e.g. MEAN, i want to print -- in the td.

i can't seem to wrap my head around how to display all mean data in a row and just replacing missing one's with a '--'...

i've tried wrapping in ng-container, several ngFor loops, yet it always comes out wrong, i.e. i get too many -- or none at all and my data is being displayed in the wrong td.

here's the html

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Code</th>
    <th scope="col">Function</th>
    <th scope="col" class="text-center"
        *ngFor="let timeStamp of maxTimeStamps; let i=index">t{{i + 1}}&#10;{{timeStamp.time}}</th>
    <th>&Delta;AUC</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let experiment of report.experiments; let i = index">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" [ngStyle]="{color: experimentColors[i]}">{{experiment.code.toUpperCase()}}</td>
    <td>mean</td>
        ------missing td goes here-------

       ----------------------------------
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If I get it you want to show your columns and data in a row?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, If I get it right you want to show your data in rows but you add ngFor in the wrong place for that (it shouldn't add to tbody tag)! please check the corrected code below.

You can change or make a condition by `ngIf` if you don't want to add that td.
Good Luck.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Code</th>
    <th scope="col">Function</th>
    <th scope="col" class="text-center"
        *ngFor="let timeStamp of maxTimeStamps; let i=index">t{{i + 1}}&#10;{{timeStamp.time}}</th>
    <th>&Delta;AUC</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let experiment of report.experiments; let i = index">
    <td rowspan="4" [ngStyle]="{color: experiment.Colors[i]}" [ngIf]="experiment.CheckableItem == true">{{experiment.code.toUpperCase()}}</td>
    <td>mean</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! i will adapt my code to that and try with an ngIf

Comment: I hope it would help, Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If some of the properties will not be available in the interface then they should be defined optional. Notice the question mark.

```js
interface TimeData {
   time?: string;
   data?: {SD?: string, SEM?: string, N?: string, MEAN?: string};
}
```

In the template, you could use `*ngIf` directive with an [`else`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else) clause to show `'--'` if some properties are not available. Try the following

Controller

```js
import { Component, VERSION, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

interface TimeData {
   time?: string;
   data?: {SD?: string, SEM?: string, N?: string, MEAN?: string};
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  timeData: TimeData[] = [
    {time: '15', data: {SD: '10', SEM: '20', N: '30', MEAN: '75'}},
    {data: {SD: '10', SEM: '20', N: '30', MEAN: '75'}},
    {time: '15', data: {SD: '10', SEM: '20', N: '30'}},
    {data: {SEM: '20', N: '30', MEAN: '75'}},
  ];

  constructor(private _router: Router, private _el: ElementRef) { }
}
```

Template

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>SD</th>
    <th>SEM</th>
    <th>N</th>
    <th>MEAN</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of timeData">
    <ng-container *ngIf="data.time; else emptyData">
      <td>{{ data.time }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="data.data.SD; else emptyData">
      <td>{{ data.data.SD }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="data.data.SEM; else emptyData">
      <td>{{ data.data.SEM }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="data.data.N; else emptyData">
      <td>{{ data.data.N }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="data.data.MEAN; else emptyData">
      <td>{{ data.data.MEAN }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #emptyData>
      <td>--</td>
    </ng-template>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gikkud3slk)